# Is it possible to access underlying Xamarin UI elements using SkiaSharp?

Tags: c#, image-processing, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

In a cross platform Xamarin.Forms application, I would like to add a SKCanvas on top of other UI elements to allow the user to draw e.g. on images. I know it is possible to load an image directly into an SKCanvas, but images are not the only application I need.

A perfect solution would be able to load the underlying content of the page, including all of its UI elements into the Canvas/Surface, so that the user can then draw on it and save the drawing + underlying content into an image (probably using the snapshot method?).

Is this possible?

Comment: So you basically need a screenshot of the current layout and load the screenshot into SkiaSharp?! What platforms do you want to support?

Comment: @MalteGoetz kind of, yes, but it also should be realtime. all three xamarin.forms mobile platforms, i.e. android, ios, uwp

Comment: realtime might be difficult the only thing I could think of would be creating screenshots constantly to get close to realtime. The screenshot thing needs a platform specific implementation then, but that should work for android, iOS and UWP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do this exactly as planned originally, but ended up doing a workaround that satisfied the requirements at the time.

I added a transparent canvas on top of my content, such that the underlying content would be shown through the canvas, but anything on the canvas would always be drawn on top. The drawings were saved and transmitted separately from the content and re-drawn when needed. On demand, when the user would need to export both together for a snapshot/share/export function, I then loaded the underlying content as image into the canvas and exported it together with the drawings from the canvas into a new image.